# Distributing Mac app outside App Store. How should I sign it?

Tags: xcode, macos, software-distribution

I have a Mac app which can't be sandboxed due to using Apple Events and therefore it can't be released through the Mac App Store.

I've made a website, added a payment gateway and everything seems to be ok but I keep getting feedback from testers who can't open the app even with the right mouse button method.
First it was the raw app from Xcode without any kind of signing, after that I tried exporting after archiving using my developer certificate, the I even notarized the app with Apple but still there are people who can't open the app (even though they was able to use it before signing).

Currently I'm using the Mac App Distribution certificate (no provisioning profile). Is this correct? Should I use "Mac Installer", "Mac developer", "Apple developer", "Apple distribution"… why is this so confusing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use the Developer ID Application certificate to distribute a Mac app outside the Mac App Store that does not use an installer. Most Mac apps do not use an installer.

Apple provides a decent explanation of the different certificates when you create a new certificate from Apple's Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles page. To keep people reading this from having to go there, I'll explain them now.

The Developer ID Installer certificate is for distributing Mac apps outside the App Store that use an installer to install the app.

The Mac Development certificate is for signing development versions of a Mac app.

The Mac App Distribution certificate is for distributing a Mac app on the App Store that does not use an installer. The Mac Installer Distribution certificate is for distributing a Mac app on the App Store that uses an installer.

In Xcode 11, Apple added the Apple Development and Apple Distribution certificates so people could sign their apps for all Apple platforms with one certificate. These certificates are for apps that will end up on the App Store.

Comment: The Mac Development certificate is for apps that will end up on the app store too?

Comment: The Mac Development certificate is for any development (pre-release) version of a Mac app. You can use the Mac Development certificate to sign a development version of a Mac app that will eventually end up on the App Store.